# How to make visible storyboard items which were added dynamically?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a rookie in iOS

I need to make visible items that I add dynamically. All settings that I make dynamically I can see just if I launch the simulator.

In my current `ViewController` I added background and label dynamically

Here my storyboard:

[image]

but here how it is actually has to be:

[image]

---

I know that one of the way to get it put this annotation `@IBDesignable` on top of class. I tried, but nope.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "but here how it is actually has to be" Why does it have to be that way? If the app works when you run it, what do you care what appears in the storyboard?

Comment: I don't understand why this question lowdown ? It is a absolutely normal question and even more it has a answer. And I am sure that it can help someone... Why this is got minus marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the way how to achieve the result

If you need your view to be visible you need to create this view as a custom.

For example background:

create you custom view class `GradientView`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class GradientView: UIView {

let backgroundGreyColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
let backgroundLightGreyColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

var gradientBackground: UIColor {
    set {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [backgroundGreyColor, backgroundLightGreyColor, backgroundGreyColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
    }
    get {
        return backgroundColor!
    }
}
}
```

Don't forget put annotation `@IBDesignable`

create your custom view:

[image]

scratch it to full screen and don't forget assigned your custom view:

[image]

And that is it! Feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

One approach is: Make your view IBDesignable and *also* implement [`prepareForInterfaceBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1402908-prepareforinterfacebuilder) to design the view as desired.

(However, it is better in my opinion not to do what you are trying to do. "Dynamic" *means* "at runtime". The storyboard is not runtime. Your app displays as desired when the app runs, so you have no problem. There is no need for the storyboard to try artificially to simulate the same thing. The storyboard is for the static part of your design, constructed graphically; code is for the dynamic part of your design, constructed in code. There is no need to make the former do the job of the latter.)